# MSSQL JSON Select column as object key

Tags: json, sql-server, object, key

I am trying to select a JSON structure directly form my MSSQL DB.

What I want is to select the ID field as the Key of an object.

Assuming I have the following columns:

```
ID | Firstname | LastName   | DateOfBirth | Gender
1  | Paul      | Van Tonder | 1990-03-11  | Male
```

I would like to select into a JSON format such as:

```
[
  {
    "1": {
        "FirstName": "Paul",
        "LastName": "Van Tonder",
        "DateOfBirth": "1990-03-11",
        "Gender": "Male"
    }

  }
]
```

Comment: Try This: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56535891/sql-server-how-to-query-data-all-rows-as-json-object-into-next-to-other-columns

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: @Zhorov - I use SQL Server 2019 Developer Edition

Answer (score 0):

I don't think, that you can generate a JSON output with variable key names using only `FOR JSON`. So, you need to use a string-based approach:

- Using only string concatenation / aggregation
- Using a combination of `FOR JSON` and string aggregation

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Data (
   ID int, 
   FirstName varchar(50), 
   LastName varchar(50), 
   DateOfBirth date, 
   Gender varchar(50)   
)
INSERT INTO Data (ID, FirstName, LastName, DateOfBirth, Gender)
VALUES 
  (1, 'Paul',  'Van Tonder', '1990-03-11', 'Male'),
  (2, 'John',  'Van Tonder', '1990-03-12', 'Male')
```

Statement (using string aggregation and concatenation):

```
SELECT CONCAT(
    '[',
    STRING_AGG(
        CONVERT(nvarchar(max), CONCAT(
            '{"FirstName":"', 
            FirstName, 
            '", "LastName":"', 
            LastName, 
            '", "DateOfBirth":"', 
            CONVERT(varchar, DateOfBirth), 
            '", "Gender": "', 
            Gender, 
            '"}')
        ),
        ','
    ),
    ']'
)
FROM Data
```

Statement (using `FOR JSON` and string aggreagtion):

```
SELECT CONCAT(
   '[',
   STRING_AGG(CONCAT('{"', d.ID, '": ',  c.Json), ','),
   ']'
   )
FROM Data d
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT FirstName, LastName, DateOfBirth, Gender 
   FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
) c (Json)
```

Result:

```
[
   {"1":{"FirstName":"Paul","LastName":"Van Tonder","DateOfBirth":"1990-03-11","Gender":"Male"}},
   {"2":{"FirstName":"John","LastName":"Van Tonder","DateOfBirth":"1990-03-12","Gender":"Male"}}
]
```

Comment: I tried this as opposed to a simple CONCAT + STUFF mixup. Which seems to be faster, but is there another way that is even faster?

Comment: @crazyvonzipper You are right about the execution time. The approach using `FOR JSON` runs slightly slower (tested with 1000000 rows), but the output is JSON, so using native JSON support is my first option. Thanks.